# Melacha explicitly in the Chumash

Tags: shabbat, torah-reading, melacha-creative-work, pentateuch-chumash

How many, and which, melachot of shabbos are explicitly mentioned in the Chumash?

For example, I know the Chumash mentions not making a fire; is this the only example of such or are there more which the Chumash states?

Comment: Some say making fire is not a melakha because it is mentioned separately

Comment: There are some examples in Tanakh but not Chumash. Are you interested in hearing those?

Comment: אֵת אֲשֶׁר־תֹּאפוּ אֵפוּ וְאֵת אֲשֶׁר־תְּבַשְּׁלוּ בַּשֵּׁלוּ, [shemos 16:23](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.16.23?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), is a non-explicit mention.

Comment: On the most basic level, I'd wager 'melacha' means any kind of work in exchange for money (or goods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the level of *peshat*, ploughing and harvesting are mentioned in [Shemot 34:21](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.34.21?lang=bi).

Also, some derive the *melachah* of *hotza'ah* ("carrying") from [Shemot 36:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.36.6?lang=bi) (see [Shabbat 96b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.96b.1?lang=bi)) or from [Shemot 16:29](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.16.29?lang=bi) (see [Eruvin 17b with Tosafot](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Eruvin.17b.12?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Eruvin.17b.12.1&lang2=bi)).

Comment: Even though it's in the question, since there is no source, and just for completeness, you may want to add havarah

שמות ל"ה:ג: לֹא־תְבַעֲר֣וּ אֵ֔שׁ בְּכֹ֖ל מֹשְׁבֹֽתֵיכֶ֑ם בְּי֖וֹם הַשַּׁבָּֽת׃
https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.35.3

Comment: Also bundling (מעמר), as in וימצאו איש מקושש עצים.